# Cannot query SQLite Android Database using primary key

Tags: android, sql, sqlite, cursor, primary-key

I have this table

```
private static final String SQL_CREATE_TABLE_TASKS = String.format("CREATE TABLE %s"
            +" (%s INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, %s TEXT, %s INTEGER, %s INTEGER, %s INTEGER)",
            DatabaseContract.TABLE_TASKS,
            TaskColumns._ID,
            TaskColumns.DESCRIPTION,
            TaskColumns.IS_COMPLETE,
            TaskColumns.IS_PRIORITY,
            TaskColumns.DUE_DATE
    );
```

The primary key of this DB is `_ID`:

```
public static final String _ID = "_id";
```

Now, here's the issue : I'm querying the database using a cursor.

If, for example, i want to retrieve a single row having primary key = 0, I should do something like this:

```
String query = "SELECT " + DatabaseContract.TaskColumns.DESCRIPTION +
                ", " + DatabaseContract.TaskColumns.DUE_DATE +
                ", " + DatabaseContract.TaskColumns.IS_COMPLETE +
                ", " + DatabaseContract.TaskColumns.IS_PRIORITY +
                " FROM " + DatabaseContract.TABLE_TASKS +
                selection +
                " ORDER BY " +
                sortOrder +
                ";";
db.rawQuery(query, null);
```

with

```
string = "SELECT description, due_date, is_complete, is_priority FROM tasks WHERE _id = '0' ORDER BY is_complete ASC, is_priority DESC, due_date ASC;"
```

It should return a cursor at the needed row in the table

But, as you can guess, I got an error:

> FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>
> Process: com.google.developer.taskmaker, PID: 4195                                                                     android.database.CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 0 requested, with a size of 0

If I'm trying to retrieve another row, for example 2, it gives me a different row than it should, like a random one.

If I'm trying to do:

```
cursor.getColumnIndex("_id");
```

to get the index of the primary key row, it will return -1 which clearly doesn't exist on a database, -1 means null pointer exception on sqlite.

If I'm accessing

```
int colIndex = -1;
cursor.getInt(colIndex);
```

to get the primary key of that row, I get an error.

Having that problem, I can't delete/update/query a specific row having it's primary key ID. I think primary key row is hidden in some way and I have to `unlock` it.

I have even with `db.update/insert/query/delete` but not working, so I switched to raw queries to have more control over it.

I have to solve that problem pretty fast, any help is appreciated.

Thanks.

**EDIT #1:**

I have figured out a thing:

when querying the database, I have incremented the ID so if the first item is needed, it will query for id=1 not for id=0. Now, i got no issues with cursor. 
But, when i try to update an entry, for example with id=2, the second entry, nothing happens. The entry #2 exists and is displayed in the recyclerview. It should make a checkbox checked if it's 1. This is the query what is executed on database:

```
query = "UPDATE tasks SET is_complete = '1' WHERE _id = '2';";
db.rawQuery(query, null);
```

after the update query, is_complete is still 0.

Comment: you have not shared enough code to figure out the issue

Comment: what code do you want to see? there's nothing that could help you understand the problem more...

Comment: Obviosuly there is no ID in selected columns

Comment: well your cursor seems to be empty, not having columns that you are looking for in it

Comment: i have added an edit to the post.

Answer (score 0):

The `_id` column is `AUTOINCREMENT`. This means that the 1st row you ever insert to the table will have `_id=1`. 
When you execute:

```
"SELECT description, due_date, is_complete, is_priority FROM tasks WHERE _id = '0' ORDER BY is_complete ASC, is_priority DESC, due_date ASC;"
```

you will get no rows because in your table there is no row with `_id=0` and there will never be.  
Also maybe there are gaps between the ids because if you delete say the row with `_id=3`, there will never be again another row with `_id=3`.

Maybe you use the value from the `_id` column in your recyclerview adapter and this messes things up, because the position of the item in the adapter has nothing to do with its `_id`.